# Ruby program gems

Tags: ruby, bundler, gemfile

I wonder whether `Gemfile` is a rails-tied file or not. If I have something as:

```
require 'json'
```

in my ruby file, the user tries to run it, and he doesn't have that gem, what will happen? How do I make sure that someone's computer knows what gems to install before running my script? I know `bundle install` exists in Rails, but what about outside Rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Gemfile](http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html) isn't a Rails-tied file. It's the file that you can use any Ruby-based project with `bundler` gem installed. Once you've run `bundle install` command, another file `Gemfile.lock` is generated or updated if exists. By the way, gems you'll use are linked with locations in your computer/server you're developing.

Comment: "By the way, gems you'll use are linked with locations in your computer/server you're developing." > that wont be an issue if the user runs bundle install right?

Comment: @TrtTrt It should be OK after `bundle install` in normal conditions.